# Get lowest price bigger than 0 of a simple "instock" product for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I am trying to get the lowest price of an available (instock) simple product when the price is bigger than 0, for a defined product category…

I have this code that displays the lowest price:

```
function wpq_get_min_price_per_product_cat($term_id){    
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "
    SELECT  MIN( meta_value+0 ) as minprice
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) 
    WHERE  
      ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN (%d) ) 
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'product'  
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_price'
    ";

    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $term_id));
}
```

But how to target "in stock" products with a price bigger than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changed SQL query will get the lowest price, for a defined product category term id, for a product price bigger than 0 and for an "in stock" product:

```
function wpq_get_min_price_per_product_cat( $term_id ){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT  MIN(pm.meta_value+0)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2
            ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
            ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt
            ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND tt.term_id = %d
        AND p.post_type = 'product'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_price'
        AND pm.meta_value > 0
        AND pm2.meta_key = '_stock_status'
        AND pm2.meta_value = 'instock'
    ", $term_id) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.